# Managing sessions with Multiple users in Shoppingcart

Tags: php, e-commerce

I am doing a PHP  based shopping cart for myproject. I am new to those technologies and i do have a questions about how to add product items to the cart before the user login.Because nowadays many online shopping cart uses that  facility.Used sessions or cookies to manage the cart.Suppose i used a session named as 'cart'.
$_SESSION['Cart'];

after i add those items in to these session array and then store in the database using session name.After User logging i replace session name with user name in the database. Suppose multiple users login for my site and add items to cart before login.Then i only create session array name 'cart' and is there would be a conflict when multiple users adding items to the cart and then  retrieving cart items for saving in the database cause i am using the same session based array?

Is there a better way to design that?

Comment: Please edit your question to be more apparent. I had a hard time understanding. Also, ask a specific question and provide your effort and we'll be glad to help

Comment: I have edited my question

Comment: You are asking if a user add something to `$_SESSION['Cart']` and other user adds too, they will overwrite or mess with that session variable ? The answer is no. Each `$_SESSION` variable is for THAT SPECIFIC USER, it is not shared between all users.

Comment: Oh that'means i declared that session variable with that name and then when i hosted in a actual server i can facilitate for multiple users.Right.?No conflicts.Thank You very much.